# Does SIP UAS/UAC must to listen to TCP and UDP protocols at the same port?

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I have freeswitch with two subscribers registered on it.
For example, A and B.
But B can't listen to TCP and UDP protocols at the same port at the same time. So if I configure B for UDP and call from A to B through freeswitch. And freeswitch tries to connect to B via TCP, then it fails and it sends 503 Service Unavailable to A.
I know about clause [8.1.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.3.1) in RFC3261. But I'm not sure about it and I want to ask what the SIP standard says about it. Shouldn't you try sending message over UDP if you unable to establish a TCP connection?
I read SIP standard, but I didn't find anything about that(maybe I missed that).
Moreover, I want to know if this is a freeswitch mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a REGISTER request from B with TCP transport in contact header then freeswitch will communicate with TCP else with UDP.
For your case, Yes its possible. UAS/UAC can listen in the same port with TCP & UDP. 
You can create a socket with TCP and UDP in code. 
Below UAS is listening at UDP & TCP.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From rfc3261:

> 18.2 Servers
>
> 18.2.1 Receiving Requests
>
> A server SHOULD be prepared to receive requests on any IP address, 
>   port and transport combination that can be the result of a DNS lookup 
>   on a SIP or SIPS URI [4] that is handed out for the purposes of
>   communicating with that server.  In this context, "handing out"
>   includes placing a URI in a Contact header field in a REGISTER
>   request or a redirect response, or in a Record-Route header field in
>   a request or response.  A URI can also be "handed out" by placing it
>   on a web page or business card.  It is also RECOMMENDED that a server 
>   listen for requests on the default SIP ports (5060 for TCP and UDP,
>   5061 for TLS over TCP) on all public interfaces.  The typical
>   exception would be private networks, or when multiple server
>   instances are running on the same host.  For any port and interface
>   that a server listens on for UDP, it MUST listen on that same port
>   and interface for TCP.  This is because a message may need to be sent 
>   using TCP, rather than UDP, if it is too large.  As a result, the
>   converse is not true.  A server need not listen for UDP on a
>   particular address and port just because it is listening on that same 
>   address and port for TCP.  There may, of course, be other reasons why 
>   a server needs to listen for UDP on a particular address and port.

In practice, a service in real life MUST listen on all mandatory transport. Otherwise users are getting into troubles.

Anyway, a client will in practice use either UDP or TCP (or TLS). But not both. This should really not be an issue if A and B are using different transport because the service (freeswitch here) should communicate with UDP for A and with TCP for B. Using different transport for each users must not be a reason for a routing failure.

To be complete, SIP servers usually cannot send message to SIP clients without an existing connection (because of NAT, firewall...). SIP clients will usually make a REGISTER (and thus, create a reusable TCP connection or a reusable UDP binding), then, when required, the server will always re-use that TCP connection or UDP binding (so called a reversed path) to forward the new request (the INVITE).

In real world, there is no other way!

Comment: Yes, the server should re-use connection if it exists, but freeswitch doesn't do that. I don't know why, but I find out that freeswitch use transport which placed at the first place in "bind-params" variable in the config. It doesn't look at REGISTER, I see it in pcap-trace. There's existing TCP connection between freeswitch and B, but if in the config a line "bind-params=udp,tcp", it will try to send a request by UDP.